# how to alert anonymous user on session timeout and redirect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, session

I have a Mock test page (without requiring authentication) and storing user selection data in session variables and on the results page retrieve the data from these sessions. Session time out is set to 20 min with sliding expiration to be true. At times user is idle for more than 20 min (default timeout).  I want to show alert only when the session is timed out and redirect. I m open to use javascript, jquery or asp.net c#. I have seen similar questions & answers Tried Global.asax session end and jquery solutions but none seems to be working for me. Can any body give me an example as per my requirements? thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24669/JavaScript-to-Show-Session-Timeout-Counter

i was having similar issues i tried this two links

i hope this will help you regards...:)

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly for me

```
 override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    //It appears from testing that the Request and Response both share the
    // same cookie collection.  If I set a cookie myself in the Reponse, it is
    // also immediately visible to the Request collection.  This just means that
    // since the ASP.Net_SessionID is set in the Session HTTPModule (which
    // has already run), thatwe can't use our own code to see if the cookie was
    // actually sent by the agent with the request using the collection. Check if
    // the given page supports session or not (this tested as reliable indicator
    // if EnableSessionState is true), should not care about a page that does
    // not need session
    if (Context.Session != null)
    {
        //Tested and the IsNewSession is more advanced then simply checking if
        // a cookie is present, it does take into account a session timeout, because
        // I tested a timeout and it did show as a new session
        if (Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
            // have timed out (can't use the cookie collection because even on first
            // request it already contains the cookie (request and response
            // seem to share the collection)
            string szCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((null != szCookieHeader) && (szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redirect", "alert('Your session has timed out due to inactivity. Please start the test again'); window.location.reload()", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 5000); 


    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0;
    });
});

function timerIncrement() {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime >12 ) { //60 secs
        alert("session expired");
        window.location.href="a3.html";
    }
}
```

this coding helps to session timeout after `60secs` and **redirect** to another page after alert